# Organic Groups D7 : How to get custom group list of login user?

Tags: organic-groups

How to get logged in user group list in select box.

Need to help Please suggest me any one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [og_get_groups_by_user](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_get_groups_by_user/7) function.

```
$current_user_groups = og_get_groups_by_user();
```